# Python Xarray, sort by index or dimension?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is there a `sort_index` or `sort_by_dimension` method of some kind in `xarray`, much like `pandas.DataFrame.sort_index()`, where I can sort a `xarray.DataArray` object by one of its dimensions? In terms of usage, I'm thinking of something like `data_array.sort(dim="dimension_name")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a good method to do this built into `xarray`, so I made a new array by taking a slice with the sorted values from the coordinate I wanted to sort: `da_sorted=da.loc[{'lon':sorted(da.coords['lon'].values)}]`

Here's a larger example with test data showing what it looks like in practice:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = np.random.rand(2, 3)

lat = [47, 45]

lon = [-118, -122, -120]
da = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[lat, lon], dims=['lat', 'lon'])


>>>> da
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 2, lon: 3)>
array([[ 0.16118 ,  0.215621,  0.599749],
       [ 0.144778,  0.984167,  0.416469]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int64 47 45
  * lon      (lon) int64 -118 -122 -120,


da_sorted = da.loc[{'lon':sorted(da.coords['lon'].values)}]
>>>> da_sorted
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 2, lon: 3)>
array([[ 0.215621,  0.599749,  0.16118 ],
       [ 0.984167,  0.416469,  0.144778]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int64 47 45
  * lon      (lon) int64 -122 -120 -118
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean rearrange the dimensions?
For example, with `.transpose()` you can reorder the dimensions of both a whole dataset or specific dataarray, e.g.

```
ds.transpose('lat','lon','time')
```

Comment: No, I mean to get a `DataArray` that is sorted by "lon" for example.

Answer (score 0):

`xarray` has now a built-in method for this task, which can be performed easily using `.sortby()` https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sortby.html

The code posted by [@Kyle Heuton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1748679/kyle-heuton) becomes now:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = np.random.rand(2, 3)

lat = [47, 45]

lon = [-118, -122, -120]
da = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[lat, lon], dims=['lat', 'lon'])


>>>> da
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 2, lon: 3)>
array([[ 0.16118 ,  0.215621,  0.599749],
       [ 0.144778,  0.984167,  0.416469]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int64 47 45
  * lon      (lon) int64 -118 -122 -120,


da_sorted = da.sortby(da.lon)
>>>> da_sorted
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 2, lon: 3)>
array([[ 0.215621,  0.599749,  0.16118 ],
       [ 0.984167,  0.416469,  0.144778]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int64 47 45
  * lon      (lon) int64 -122 -120 -118
```